# Loading Core ML Model in Swift

Tags: swift, swift-playground, coreml, apple-vision

I am trying to make an app playground that will classify a photo as Apple or Orange. I have a model file called "AppleOrange.mlmodel" that is trained for this. But I cannot load the model file.

My code:

```swift
func classifyImage(imageName: String, modelName: String) -> String {
    guard let modelPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: modelName, ofType: "mlmodel") else {
        return "Error: Could not find model."
    }

    let modelURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: modelPath)
    guard let model = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: MLModel(contentsOf: modelURL)) else {
        return "Error: Could not load model."
    }

    guard let image = UIImage(named: imageName)?.cgImage else {
        return "Error: Could not load image."
    }

    let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model) {
        [self] (request, error) in
        guard let results = request.results as? [VNClassificationObservation], let topResult = results.first else {
            return
        }
        let confidence = topResult.confidence * 100
        let fruit = topResult.identifier
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.classificationResult = "This is a \(fruit) with \(String(format: "%.2f", confidence))% confidence."
        }
    }

    let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: image)
    try? handler.perform([request])
    return ""
}
```

Comment: What is the error you get ? Always try to print error an/or error.localizedFezcription.

Comment: try using `mlmodelc` instead of `mlmodel
`